# how find collective range in two period in database

Tags: sql, database, date, date-range

i have a table in database , and i want write query code to select collective date between two record .

this is sample code :

> table is :

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `startdate` date NOT NULL,
  `enddate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
)
```

example 1
and i have 2 record  in table .

> (userid =>1 , startdate => '2012-02-02' , enddate => '2012-10-02')
>   (userid =>2 , startdate => '2012-04-02' , enddate => '2012-09-02')

i want select query to give range '2012-04-02' until '2012-09-02'

example 2
and i have 2 record  in table .

> (userid =>1 , startdate => '2012-02-02' , enddate => '2012-02-12')
>   (userid =>2 , startdate => '2012-04-02' , enddate => '2012-09-02')

i want select query to give null range

is there best query for this?

Comment: What means 'select collective date between two record ' ? Can you post sample with data? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: please provide sample data and O/P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've got it right and you need time period that is an intersection of periods from these rows:

```
select * from
(
    select max(startdate) d1, min(enddate) d2 from user
) where d1<=d2
```

Comment: if my data is (userid =>1 , startdate => '2012-02-02' , enddate => '2012-02-10') (userid =>2 , startdate => '2012-04-02' , enddate => '2012-09-02') this code can not return collective date

Comment: I've fixed query to handle case like that

Comment: thanks valex i think you should `as t` after (
    select max(startdate) d1, min(enddate) d2 from user
)

Comment: @aya If you use MySQL then YES - you should give a name for a subquery in FROM class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want,

```
  select userid,min(startdate),max(enddate),abs(max(enddate)-min(startdate)) as range 
  from user group by userid;
```